# Error apt-get install apache 2

Tags: apt

I need to install apache 2 in order to installe nagios xi but when I run the command

```
apt-get install apache 2
```

it shows an error saying

```
unable to locate apache 2
```

I use Ubuntu 13.10  and I already used `apt-get update` and `upgrade` but still unable  to locate apache 2.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you add the **exact** command you tried along with its **exact** and **full** output in terminal?

Comment: Preferably copy and paste.

Comment: @Braiam see http://askubuntu.com/questions/421541/error-apt-get-install-apache-2/421542#comment544575_421542

Comment: hi the commande i use is apt-get install apache2 i thinkit's correct

Answer (score 4):

It isn't `apache 2` or `appach2` it's `apache2`. So try the below  command to install the `apache2` package:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: dude i said i already used that and even i updated every thing but still nth

Comment: @OuSs: Did you put a space in your command? There is a small but important difference. The command in your example had a space.

Comment: plz post the command you tried along with it's output.

Comment: yea i know that's not it

Comment: i tried the command sudo apt-get install appach2

Comment: `sudo apt-get install apache2`.I provided this on my answer.